# How to create a menu system for a console, terminal application

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, console

I looked for "How to create a menu system for a console, terminal application". None of the proposed Similar questions fully answered my goal.

1. Add a menu to a console application to manage activities.
2. Run a selected function.
3. Clear the output
4. Display the menu again or exit if done is selected

Therefore, I am approaching this as a Q&A format. [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.97617887.1183206830.1649779840-670833223.1638109562)

Suggested better answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"""
1. Add a menu to a console application to manage activities.
2. Run a selected function.
3. Clear the output
4. Display the menu again or exit if done is selected
"""

import sys
from os import system


def display_menu(menu):
    """
    Display a menu where the key identifies the name of a function.
    :param menu: dictionary, key identifies a value which is a function name
    :return:
    """
    for k, function in menu.items():
        print(k, function.__name__)


def one():
    print("you have selected menu option one") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def two():
    print("you have selected menu option two") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def three():
    print("you have selected menu option three") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def done():
    system('cls')  # clears stdout
    print("Goodbye")
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Create a menu dictionary where the key is an integer number and the
    # value is a function name.
    functions_names = [one, two, three, done]
    menu_items = dict(enumerate(functions_names, start=1))

    while True:
        display_menu(menu_items)
        selection = int(
            input("Please enter your selection number: "))  # Get function key
        selected_value = menu_items[selection]  # Gets the function name
        selected_value()  # add parentheses to call the function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a similar functionality and found this package: [console_menu](https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/) on PyPI. I haven't tried it out yet but apparently it should be simple to use. I copy their documentation example below.

```
# Import the necessary packages
from consolemenu import *
from consolemenu.items import *

# Create the menu
menu = ConsoleMenu("Title", "Subtitle")

# Create some items

# MenuItem is the base class for all items, it doesn't do anything when selected
menu_item = MenuItem("Menu Item")

# A FunctionItem runs a Python function when selected
function_item = FunctionItem("Call a Python function", input, ["Enter an input"])

# A CommandItem runs a console command
command_item = CommandItem("Run a console command",  "touch hello.txt")

# A SelectionMenu constructs a menu from a list of strings
selection_menu = SelectionMenu(["item1", "item2", "item3"])

# A SubmenuItem lets you add a menu (the selection_menu above, for example)
# as a submenu of another menu
submenu_item = SubmenuItem("Submenu item", selection_menu, menu)

# Once we're done creating them, we just add the items to the menu
menu.append_item(menu_item)
menu.append_item(function_item)
menu.append_item(command_item)
menu.append_item(submenu_item)

# Finally, we call show to show the menu and allow the user to interact
menu.show()
```