# How to make a function (python) to change a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a function, witch could change a variable that we can choose via the input() function. The variable being diferent every time, so I cant just use global.

I could do it with if statements, but I have a lot of variables and I don't want to write that way. I also want to learn the proper way of coding.

A nice example I found is for creating a menu ([How to create a menu system for a console, terminal application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943877/how-to-create-a-menu-system-for-a-console-terminal-application)). The code from this link:

```
"""
1. Add a menu to a console application to manage activities.
2. Run a selected function.
3. Clear the output
4. Display the menu again or exit if done is selected
"""

import sys
from os import system


def display_menu(menu):
    """
    Display a menu where the key identifies the name of a function.
    :param menu: dictionary, key identifies a value which is a function name
    :return:
    """
    for k, function in menu.items():
        print(k, function.__name__)


def one():
    print("you have selected menu option one") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def two():
    print("you have selected menu option two") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def three():
    print("you have selected menu option three") # Simulate function output.
    input("Press Enter to Continue\n")
    system('cls')  # clears stdout


def done():
    system('cls')  # clears stdout
    print("Goodbye")
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Create a menu dictionary where the key is an integer number and the
    # value is a function name.
    functions_names = [one, two, three, done]
    menu_items = dict(enumerate(functions_names, start=1))

    while True:
        display_menu(menu_items)
        selection = int(
            input("Please enter your selection number: "))  # Get function key
        selected_value = menu_items[selection]  # Gets the function name
        selected_value()  # add parentheses to call the function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there a way to do the same with a variable? To store the name in an array and then assigned it to a different variable (here called selected_value, but in this function, it would be called selected_variable) so we can change it later with selected_variable=input()?

Comment: Use a dictionary to store the values that could be changed by the user. Having a function accessing the global (which is like a dictionary btw) could be a problem if the user chooses a variable she wasn't suppose to change.

Comment: [Here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for dictionaries. The example you posted is using a dictionary. I think what you are trying to do is `print('Current menu items', menu_items); key = input('What item in the menu would you like to change: '); value = input('What would you like the new value to be: '); menu_items[key] = value; print('changed menu items', menu_items)`