# The fox, chicken and grain game, how do i change the value of the variables when i dont know what the user will input and is match case easier?

Tags: python, variables

```
#imports
import sys
# Fox, chicken, grain program

# Main Program

#Below is code that asks for a choice from the user on which of the 4 variables they would like to move
choice = input("\nA fox, chicken and a bag og grain wait by the side of a river.\n\nWhich item will you take in your rowboat to the other side?\n\nfox, chicken, grain or farmer?\n\nChoose: ")
#Make choice upper so when == is used it doesnt need to specify every possible input
choice = choice.upper()
#Making all choices = 0 so we can change their state with an integer so inputs and if/match case statements are easier to use
FARMER = 0
FOX = 0
CHICKEN = 0
GRAIN = 0
#Now we take the input from the user and change the value of whoever was chosen to 1
if choice == "FARMER" and FARMER == 0:
    FARMER = 1
elif choice == "FOX" and FOX == 0 and FARMER == 0:
    FOX = 1
    FARMER = 1
elif choice == "CHICKEN" and CHICKEN == 0 and FARMER == 0:
    CHICKEN = 1
    FARMER = 1
elif choice == "GRAIN" and GRAIN == 0 and FARMER == 0:
    GRAIN = 1
    FARMER = 1
elif choice == "GRAIN" and GRAIN == 0:
    GRAIN = 1
    FARMER = 1
#Sub Programs: These will hold the output of what will be given to the user to show the outcome of the users choice and where things currently are
def output():
    print("\n -----------------------------------")
    if FARMER == 1:
        print("\nThe Farmer is on the left of the river.")
    if FOX == 1:
        print("\nThe Fox is on the left of the river.")
    if CHICKEN == 1:
        print("\nThe Chicken is on the left of the river.")
    if GRAIN == 1:
        print("\nThe Grain is on the left of the river.")
    if FARMER == 0:
        print("\nThe Farmer is on the right of the river.")
    if FOX == 0:
        print("\nThe Fox is on the right of the river.")
    if CHICKEN == 0:
        print("\nThe Chicken is on the right of the river.")
    if GRAIN == 0:
        print("\nThe Grain is on the right of the river.")
    print("\n -----------------------------------")
#new subprogram defines the wrong move to be made.
def wrong_move():
    if FARMER == 1 and FOX == 0 and CHICKEN == 0:
        print("\nThe fox ate the chicken")
        return True
    elif FARMER == 1 and CHICKEN == 0 and GRAIN == 0:
        print("\nThe chicken ate the grain")
        sys.exit()
        return True
    else:
        return False
    

#Main Program
output()
wrong_move()
#This part is meant to allow the user to return to the other side of the river with any of the animals
if FARMER == 1 and FOX == 0 and GRAIN == 0 and CHICKEN == 1:
    input("\nWhat will you do next?: ")

output()
```

This is my current code and i've managed to show when the game should end and the start of the game where you choose who you want to move over, it outputs who is on what side however i dont know which variable they will move next so how do i change the variable like from a 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 regardless of whether i know what the value of the variable is.

I havent tried anything yet because i dont know where to even start, could it be improved at all as well

Comment: you just need to track 2 options, 1 state so which question are you on and the value for said question

Comment: see [this](https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943877/how-to-create-a-menu-system-for-a-console-terminal-application)

Comment: You can check every possible input, or use a dict for your state data {'farmer': 0, 'fox': 0, ...}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do it.

```
answer = input("What is your move?")

# if they want to move the chicken
if answer == "CHICKEN":
    # if chicken is on the right, move it to the left
    if CHICKEN == 0:
        CHICKEN = 1
    # otherwise chicken was on the left, so move it to the right
    else:
        CHICKEN = 0
```

Comment: There is no need for the second condition . With 1, 0 being equivalent to True, False you could use: `if answer == "CHICKEN":   CHICKEN = not CHICKEN` to just invert the value.

Comment: @user19077881 Clever!  There is the side effect of transforming integer values into booleans (i.e. `not 0` is `True` instead of `1`)

Comment: Sure, but the whole code is really about True and False not about Integer values so may as well be written that way throughout.

Comment: Thanks guys i think i understand and ill try that :)